# geojson coordinates to line

Tags: leaflet, coordinates, geojson

I would like to show geojson point coordinates as a line on a leaflet map.
A simplified code with some test data looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>  
    <!-- Load leaflet library and use its styling css        -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js">  </script>
    
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />  //not included
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pagewrapper">
        <div id="map"></div>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    //add map and set view
    var map =  L.map('map').setView([48.8,13.03],6);
      
    // add background layer "opentopomap"
    var backgroundlayer = L.tileLayer ('https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
    map.addLayer(backgroundlayer);
  
    //get geojson data
    function myFunction() {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:"json",
        url: "https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_50m_populated_places.geojson",
        method: 'GET',
              success: function(response) {
            visualizer.sendDataToMap(response);
              },
              error:function(error) {
              }
            });
        
        var visualizer = {};

    //make geojson object and add to map  
        visualizer.sendDataToMap = function(jsonData) {
            L.geoJson(jsonData).addTo(map);;
             };
        };

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The part "visualizer.sendDataToMap(..)" might seem strange but is needed for some reason.
I managed to show the points on the map. But what I need is to show them as line (connect the first point with the second, connect the second point with the third ..).
I thought about writing the coordinates into an array which I then can use further in L.polyline() and use for some other calculations. I tried with response.geometry.coordinates and fiddled around with "coordsToLatLng" and some other suggestions I found in the forum. Maybe I need to loop through the coordinates, but I dont know how to do that. Could not get anything to work with my example.
Any hints would be appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the coordinates from the geojson features by looping over geojson features array and mapping latitude and longitude. Then you will end up with an array of latLngs which is what you want to create the lines between the marker coordinates.

```
  //make geojson object and add to map  
        visualizer.sendDataToMap = function(jsonData) {
          console.log(jsonData)
          L.geoJson(jsonData).addTo(map);
          const latlngs = jsonData.features.map(feature => [feature.properties.LATITUDE, feature.properties.LONGITUDE]);
          L.polyline(latlngs, {
            color: 'red'
          }).addTo(map);

        };
      };
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/geojson-coordinates-to-line-3dp31)

Comment: Great, thanks very much. You really helped me a big step further in my little project.